# how to find grails dynamic method source code

Tags: grails, grails-orm

What's a good way to find source code that would get generated for methods like :  'findBy' or 'addTo'  that get dynamically created for domain classes?
I am really curious what the 'addTo' method really does.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can access the Grails source code via their Git repository, as long as you have a Git client you can check out the source here:

```
git clone http://github.com/grails/grails-core.git
```

all the details to access it are here:

http://www.grails.org/GrailsDevEnvironment

Comment: The source is distributed with your Grails install, so it's best to look there since it'll correspond to what you're using. The current Github code is pre-M1 1.4 code.